# angular2 returning object object

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am trying to show a specific username from an array. I have a user class with username, userid and other stuff. I want to call `<p>{{users$ | async).username</p>` but when I do I don't get anything. and if I only call `<p>{{users$}}</p> I get [object object]`.

In the `component.ts` I call `private users$: Observable<Users[]>;`
and   `this.users$ = this._UserService.get();`

```
 getUsers(): Observable<Users[]> {
    return this._store.select(state => state.Users.users);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: {{users$|async)[0].username       OR   use  {{users$|async)?.[0].username

Answer (score 0):

```
return this._store.select(state => state.Users.users);
```

Either you made a grammar mistake, or have several users.

Try with

```
{{ users$ | async)[0]?.username }}
```

Use the **[Elvis operator](https://hackernoon.com/the-angry-angular-asyncpipe-the-evil-elvis-operator-89293e37e04d)** to avoid getting errors

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a specific username, you have to select the user from the users first.

`users$ | async` wil get you an array.

If you know the index of the user that you want to show, use it:

```
(users$ | async)[index].username
```

`{{users$}}` will get you `[object object]`, because it is an `Observable`.

Comment: Yes I have serveral user but I want to show the specifik users name when i click on the user

Comment: Where do you click on the user? How is your template looks like? Update your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what need to be done.

On your component:

```
 this._UserService.getUser().subscribe(
          data => {
          console.log("User:", data);
            return this.user$ = data;
          },
          error => {
            console.log("Problem!!!", error);

          }
);
```

On your view:

```
{{user$.username}}
```